# Should the limit of storage for a contract be considered for Ethereum Dapps?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

In my understanding, EVM storage for each contract has 2^256 slots with 256 bit data per each slot.

When designing sustainable Dapps, should I be standing on the assumption that storage of a contract run out some day ?

I'd love to hear hints or advice to deepen my knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about storage space to run out.

But you should keep the information you store on **storage** at a minimum because it's **extremely expensive**.